# Solving nonnegative linear system in R

Tags: r, numerical-computing

Is it possible to find a solution to the undetermined system Ax = b, x >= 0 using some native R function? I can certainly write a linear program and use lpsolve, but am hoping for something native.

Comment: Sure.  What's your objective function?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I found what I was looking for. The package `nnls` addresses exactly my problem.